# WHILE UNIX SCRIPTING

Tags: loops, unix, while-loop

I am trying to create a condition with the following.

1. No special char / letters allowed.
2. Not more than 10

I have a problem that even my input is pure integer still return invalid input. Please see my script below

```
while :
do
while :
do
read -p "Please enter the R3 number(should be 10char): " CtrlNumber
count2=`echo -e "$CtrlNumber\c" | wc -m`
if [ ! -z $count2 -o $count2 -eq $count2 2>/dev/null ] ; then
CtrlNumber=$CtrlNumber
break;
elif [ $count2 -eq 10 ]   ;
then
CtrlNumber=$CtrlNumber
break;
elif [ $count2 -lt 10 ] ;
then
CtrlNumber=$(Counter)
break;

elif [ $count2 -gt 10 ] ;
then
echo "Control number is more than 10"
CtrlNumber=$CtrlNumber
fi
done
```

Comment: Tried to modify my script to

Comment: Problem is the script is not adding zeroes and still accepting char/special char

Comment: My "$(Counter)" is a method that add zeroes if the input is lt 10